# Trying to figure out how to use WHERE with one date to another date

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm taking a course in mysql and I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how do a WHERE date to some date. I've checked several website for references but none had an example.

Here is my LIMIT code that does the same result but I need to do a code similar  with a WHERE

```
SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY sign_up_date LIMIT 6 OFFSET 4;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * FROM tablename 
   WHERE columname BETWEEN '2012-12-17 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-25 23:59:59'
```